# Mapping a product into a local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

All rings considered are unital commutative. I have been bugged by the following claim.

> Let $R=A \times B$ be product of two rings. Suppose $S$ is a local ring.
> Then the canonical map induced from projections
> $$ \operatorname{Hom}(A,S) \sqcup \operatorname{Hom}(B,S) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(R,S) $$
> is surjective.

---

I understand:

- any map induced by projection must be constant on one factor.
- For $s \in S$: either $s$ or $1-s$ is a unit.

But can't really see how I can put the secondition into use. Any hint would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:R \rightarrow S$. Then $f(0,1),f(1,0)$ are idempotent elements of $S$ adding up to one, so one of them is zero. If for instance $f(0,1)=0$, then $f$ comes from a morphism $A\rightarrow S$.

Comment: Do you mean "idempotent" instead of "unipotent"? 0 can't be unipotent.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: thanks, I corrected.